# "error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0" when trying to convert a json file into a data frame

Tags: json, r, api

New to this forum with my first question and 3 days of experience with R, json data, and APIs, so please excuse any naivety. However, really excited about learning this!!

I am trying to convert a json data from the following API endpoint into a usable data frame. Here is the link to json: *https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=ETHBTC*. I am using following code to do this (simplified):

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

endpoint <- "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=ETHBTC"
dt_text <- content(GET(endpoint), "text")
dt_json <- fromJSON(dt_text, flatten = TRUE)
df_GetDepth <- as.data.frame(dt_json)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0**
```

On debugging, the error is in the last line, most likely because the first column in the json data has only one entry, whereas other columns appear to have more. Also attached is a summary snippet of the json data:

```
{
  "lastUpdateId": 1027024,
  "bids": [
    [
      "4.00000000",     // PRICE
      "431.00000000",   // QTY
      []                // Can be ignored
    ]
  ],
  "asks": [
    [
      "4.00000200",
      "12.00000000",
      []
    ]
  ]
}
```

Really look forward to learning from the experts!!

Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Using a subset of the data (omitting `"lastUpdateId"`, and only the first three of each of `"asks"` and `"bids"`), use one of:

```
dt2 <- lapply(dt_json, head, 3)[c("bids","asks")]
dt2 <- structure(list(bids = list(list("0.05309400", "8.00000000", character(0)), 
    list("0.05308800", "25.79300000", character(0)), list("0.05308600", 
        "8.25500000", character(0))), asks = list(list("0.05317900", 
    "0.15500000", character(0)), list("0.05319400", "0.04100000", 
    character(0)), list("0.05319600", "1.50000000", character(0)))), .Names = c("bids", 
"asks"))

str(dt2)
# List of 2
#  $ bids:List of 3
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ : chr "0.05309400"
#   .. ..$ : chr "8.00000000"
#   .. ..$ : chr(0) 
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ : chr "0.05308800"
#   .. ..$ : chr "25.79300000"
#   .. ..$ : chr(0) 
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ : chr "0.05308600"
#   .. ..$ : chr "8.25500000"
#   .. ..$ : chr(0) 
#  $ asks:List of 3
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ : chr "0.05317900"
#   .. ..$ : chr "0.15500000"
#   .. ..$ : chr(0) 
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ : chr "0.05319400"
#   .. ..$ : chr "0.04100000"
#   .. ..$ : chr(0) 
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ : chr "0.05319600"
#   .. ..$ : chr "1.50000000"
#   .. ..$ : chr(0)
```

The first step, rbind-ing things:

```
dt3 <- lapply(dt2, function(a) do.call(rbind, lapply(a, function(b) rbind(Filter(length, b)))))
dt3
# $bids
#      [,1]         [,2]         
# [1,] "0.05309400" "8.00000000" 
# [2,] "0.05308800" "25.79300000"
# [3,] "0.05308600" "8.25500000" 
# $asks
#      [,1]         [,2]        
# [1,] "0.05317900" "0.15500000"
# [2,] "0.05319400" "0.04100000"
# [3,] "0.05319600" "1.50000000"
```

And then converting to numbers:

```
dt4 <- lapply(dt3, function(a) t(apply(a, 1, as.numeric)))
dt4
# $bids
#          [,1]   [,2]
# [1,] 0.053094  8.000
# [2,] 0.053088 25.793
# [3,] 0.053086  8.255
# $asks
#          [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] 0.053179 0.155
# [2,] 0.053194 0.041
# [3,] 0.053196 1.500
```

This produces matrices, which should be easy enough to convert if needed to data.frames and apply column names.